# Need help writing xpath expression on xml response returned from WeatherWS app

Tags: xml, xpath, soap

I'm struggling to write an xpath expression to extract values returned from the following xml response.

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetCityForecastByZIPResponse xmlns="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/">
         <GetCityForecastByZIPResult>
            <Success>true</Success>
            <ResponseText>City Found</ResponseText>
            <State>MD</State>
            <City>Columbia</City>
            <WeatherStationCity>Baltimore</WeatherStationCity>
            <ForecastResult>
               <Forecast>
                  <Date>2011-10-08T00:00:00</Date>
                  <WeatherID>4</WeatherID>
                  <Desciption>Sunny</Desciption>
                  <Temperatures>
                     <MorningLow>48</MorningLow>
                     <DaytimeHigh>78</DaytimeHigh>
                  </Temperatures>
                  <ProbabilityOfPrecipiation>
                     <Nighttime>00</Nighttime>
                     <Daytime>00</Daytime>
                  </ProbabilityOfPrecipiation>
               </Forecast>
               <Forecast>
                  <Date>2011-10-09T00:00:00</Date>
                  <WeatherID>4</WeatherID>
                  <Desciption>Sunny</Desciption>
                  <Temperatures>
                     <MorningLow>50</MorningLow>
                     <DaytimeHigh>83</DaytimeHigh>
                  </Temperatures>
                  <ProbabilityOfPrecipiation>
                     <Nighttime>00</Nighttime>
                     <Daytime>00</Daytime>
                  </ProbabilityOfPrecipiation>
               </Forecast>
               <Forecast>
                  <Date>2011-10-10T00:00:00</Date>
                  <WeatherID>4</WeatherID>
                  <Desciption>Sunny</Desciption>
                  <Temperatures>
                     <MorningLow>53</MorningLow>
                     <DaytimeHigh>82</DaytimeHigh>
                  </Temperatures>
                  <ProbabilityOfPrecipiation>
                     <Nighttime>00</Nighttime>
                     <Daytime>00</Daytime>
                  </ProbabilityOfPrecipiation>
               </Forecast>
               <Forecast>
                  <Date>2011-10-11T00:00:00</Date>
                  <WeatherID>2</WeatherID>
                  <Desciption>Partly Cloudy</Desciption>
                  <Temperatures>
                     <MorningLow>57</MorningLow>
                     <DaytimeHigh>78</DaytimeHigh>
                  </Temperatures>
                  <ProbabilityOfPrecipiation>
                     <Nighttime>10</Nighttime>
                     <Daytime>10</Daytime>
                  </ProbabilityOfPrecipiation>
               </Forecast>
               <Forecast>
                  <Date>2011-10-12T00:00:00</Date>
                  <WeatherID>6</WeatherID>
                  <Desciption>Showers</Desciption>
                  <Temperatures>
                     <MorningLow>60</MorningLow>
                     <DaytimeHigh>71</DaytimeHigh>
                  </Temperatures>
                  <ProbabilityOfPrecipiation>
                     <Nighttime>50</Nighttime>
                     <Daytime>60</Daytime>
                  </ProbabilityOfPrecipiation>
               </Forecast>
               <Forecast>
                  <Date>2011-10-13T00:00:00</Date>
                  <WeatherID>6</WeatherID>
                  <Desciption>Showers</Desciption>
                  <Temperatures>
                     <MorningLow>61</MorningLow>
                     <DaytimeHigh>69</DaytimeHigh>
                  </Temperatures>
                  <ProbabilityOfPrecipiation>
                     <Nighttime>60</Nighttime>
                     <Daytime>50</Daytime>
                  </ProbabilityOfPrecipiation>
               </Forecast>
               <Forecast>
                  <Date>2011-10-14T00:00:00</Date>
                  <WeatherID>2</WeatherID>
                  <Desciption>Partly Cloudy</Desciption>
                  <Temperatures>
                     <MorningLow>59</MorningLow>
                     <DaytimeHigh>70</DaytimeHigh>
                  </Temperatures>
                  <ProbabilityOfPrecipiation>
                     <Nighttime>30</Nighttime>
                     <Daytime>40</Daytime>
                  </ProbabilityOfPrecipiation>
               </Forecast>
            </ForecastResult>
         </GetCityForecastByZIPResult>
      </GetCityForecastByZIPResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Can someone write the xpath expression to extract the Success property value 'true' from this response.

I've been using the following online tool - http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html to test my attempts, but each attempt as returned !NO MATCH.

Here is the xpath expression i though was correct:

```
//GetCityForecastByZIPResponse//GetCityForecastByZIPResult//Success
```

Hope someone can help.

p.S the webservice used to generate this response can be found here:
http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx - I'm using the GetCityForecastByZIP  service.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to namespaces so you either have to 'register' them upfront in your used XPath engine or simply use a XPath based solely on the element name like below

```
//*[local-name()='GetCityForecastByZIPResponse']/*[local-name()='GetCityForecastByZIPResult']/*[local-name()='Success']
```